# Where was this wallpaper taken? (Windows 8 Developer/Consumer/Release Preview lock screen)

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth, islands, lock-screens

This is a lock screen wallpaper from Windows 8 Developer/Consumer/Release Preview, where was this taken? [image]

Comment: Right click on the image above in Chrome and select *Search Google for image*

Comment: @HankyPanky in this particular case, that doesn't yield meaningful results ...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it’s not about travelling

Comment: @Traveller We've traditionally accepted "Where is this place?" questions.

Comment: I was taken from C:\Windows\Web\wallpaper :) haha

Comment: @BréntRussęll No. Lock screen wallpapers is stored in C:\Windows\Web\Screens.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick This lock screen image is from Windows 8 Developer Preview not 10. Spotlight didn't exist in Windows 8.

Comment: @Yue Ling One could also argue that it was taken directly from the photographers memory card before it even hit Windows 8.

Comment: Why is this question marked as duplicate when this one is different?